# Multi site root site installed on subdomain, with child sites as subdirectories

Tags: multisite, directory, subdomains

I have a WordPress multi site installed at `dev.example.com`, and network enabled, using subdirectories.

If I am logged into `dev.example.com/wp-admin`, and then visit `dev.example.com/site2`, I lose the horizontal admin navigation bar at top of the page, and when I revisit `dev.example.com/wp-admin` I am forced to log in again.

I have confirmed my primary admin account is an admin account for `/site2`

I have the following in my `.htaccess`:

```
# begin WordPress
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# end WordPress
```

Previously this code was missing, but adding it did not resolve the problem.

I have the following in my `wp-config.php`:

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'dev.example.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

I checked Chrome's cookies, and there is no cookie for `dev.example.com/site2`.

I can log into other multi site networks fine.

Help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because your authentication cookie is set to dev.example.com/site1/ when you login to site1, and naturally the browser won't pass that cookie for site2.

What you can try and do is play around with the `SITECOOKIEPATH` and `ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH`, which by default are set as follows:

- `SITECOOKIEPATH` to `get_option('siteurl')`
- `ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH` as `SITECOOKIEPATH . 'wp-admin'`

So changing the `SITECOOKIEPATH` through your wp-config.php file to something that will be shared between both sites should work, for example `/`. I'm not sure what will happen to the `ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH` at that point but my guess is that the default value will not work anymore, since your wp-admin directories are in different locations. I don't think you can set `ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH` in a plugin because the default gets set quite early, so I guess you'll have to use sunrise.php if you want to set it to something like `get_option('siteurl') . 'wp-admin'`.

Comment: Thanks. Bear in mind the main site is `dev.example.com/wp-admin`, not `dev.example.com/site1/wp-admin`. Does this change things?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, the `/` path will be shared across all of them but as I mentioned, you'll have to play around with `ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH` to get it right.

Comment: OK. It's unusual, because I have another MU install on a subdomain, with subdirectory child sites, and that install doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I've just created another WP install @ `test.example.com`, turned it into a MU network with sub-directories, and the symptom above did not occur. I will use `test` instead of `dev` for now. Thanks.